# upload old php and mysql version website to server which has new php, mysql version

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I have a forge account. The server has php7.3, mysql8.0, nginx configured.
I have a website which require apache server and it was developed in php5.6 and mysql5.5 version.
So my question is can I run this website in my forge server?

Comment: Maybe a good start is read the official docs - https://www.php.net/migration70

Comment: I don't want to migrate from php5.6 to php7.0. I just wondered if it can work in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to figure out is to see if your code contains functions or structures that have been deprecated with PHP7.x.

As mentioned by Angel, reading the migration documentation and more specifically the [backward incompatible changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) and the [deprecated features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) will help you check the compatibility of your code with your new environment.

You're not migrating from PHP5.6 to PHP7.0, but you're moving from one server with PHP5.6 to a server with PHP7.3, which will result to the exact same thing...

Comment: ok. but what about mysql and nginx in the case I want to use nginx instead apache?

Comment: Nginx is uncorrelated to your PHP version. It will work anyway. MySQL too. You don't take much risks copying your files and DB to the new server and see if it works or not. You can stop the old one only when you have a working setup.